# AngularJS/AJAX Authentication using Spring Security - return JSON response

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

**Spring Security Configuration**

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/myapp" always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthenticationFailureHandler" />

<bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="com.myapp.auth.AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

<bean id="myAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        class="com.myapp.auth.AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
```

**The Success and Failure Handler Bean classes:**

```
public class AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends
SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.getWriter().print(
            "{'login': 'SUCCESS'}");
    response.getWriter().flush();

}}


public class AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler extends
SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("Login Failed...");
    response.getWriter().print(
            "{'login': 'FAIL'}");
    response.getWriter().flush();

}}
```

**Question:**
The login form is submitted via AJAX/Angular application as a Form Post, but the response is expected as a JSON (no redirects)

The login success case invokes onAuthenticationSuccess successfully, so i can return JSON.
But login failure case ***does not*** invoke onAuthenticationFailure at all. Instead i see 401 response directly.
What am i doing wrong ? Or Any other ideas to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct method signature for onAuthenticationFailure in AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler is (note the last parameter of this method):

```
public void onAuthenticationFailure(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, 
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
{

    try {
        response.getWriter().print(
                "{'login': 'FAILURE'}");
        response.getWriter().flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That resolves the problem.

Comment: does it helped you to manage session or logged in session while using `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler ` ? Because what I am thinking to use is `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`. I am not well aware about the difference between them. Can you help ?

Comment: agpt> I don't know about SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler .. sorry about that. Perhaps check the javadocs...

Comment: Ok.. no issue, but can you brief how exactly you are maintaining session / cookies at javascript side ? have you faced any issues ? Thanks

Comment: agpt> This is automatically done by Spring Security - we do not need to handle that explicitly. Using any Browser developer tool Or Fiddler you can see http exchange of information with cookies etc.